# Why are there Yandex apps' APK files inside of my Samsung Galaxy A20s?

Tags: applications, samsung, apk, files

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy A20s (the model is SM-A207F/DS). I was using FX File Explorer (without root) to explore the Android filesystem of my phone. If some file was interesting, I would copy it to my storage and check it out.

While searching, I found some APKs like: Yandex Search, ruMail, and Yandex Zen. These apps were never installed on my phone, and they appear inside the `/product/preload` directory:

- The ruMail and Yandex Zen are in `/product/preload/SER/hidden_app`
- The Yandex Search is in the `/product/preload/app/yandex.search` directory

[image: The directories]

Where do these apps come from?

Comment: Looks like [Yandex and Samsung have been in a partnership since 2011](https://yandex.com/company/press_center/press_releases/2011/2011-10-25/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some device come with optional pre-installed apps. Those apps can be installed on first start, but they are not always installed (in difference to system apps which come pre-installed). As it is not sure that there is internet connectivity such apps are included into the system firmware.

On first start the apps to-be-installed are selected based on criteria like the country you are living in.

It seems like you have discovered the optional pre-loaded apps that are installed in some countries (e.g. Russia?). But you have never seen them installed you seem to live in a country where those apps are not automatically installed. But the APK files are still present so you were able to find them.